# DJANGO error. Reverse for 'receipt' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['receipt/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/$'] trying to use ID:PK

Tags: python, html, django

Lots going on here, the last row in inventory.Html is suppose to link to a product page using the id from PRODUCTS in views.py. I am trying to create a page for each product using the ID but the path isn't working.

inventory.html code

```
                    {% for i in items %}
                    
                
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{i.Name_of_the_Material_per_specification}}</td>
                            <td>{{i.Site_Material_Code }}</td>
                            <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{% url 'receipt' products.id %}">View</a></td>
                            
                            
                        </tr>
                        
                    
                    {% endfor %}
```

RECIEPT.HTML

```
    <div class="col-md">
            <div class="card card-body">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {% for i in products %}

                        <p>Name: {{products.Name_of_the_Material_per_specification}}</p>
                        
                        
                        {% endfor %}
        
            </div>
        </div>
```

URLS.PY

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from inventory import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('main', views.inventory, name='inventory'),
    path('receipt/<str:pk>/', views.products, name="receipt")
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse

from django.template import loader
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from .models import *
from .forms import *



# Create your views here.
def inventory(request):
    items = materialForm.objects.all()
  
    return render(request, 'website/inventory.html', {'items': items})

def products(request, pk):
    products = materialForm.objects.get(id=pk)
    context = {'products':products }

    return render(request, 'website/receipt.html', context )
```

models.py

```
class materialForm(models.Model):

    Name_of_the_Material_per_specification = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name_of_the_Material_per_specification
```

Comment: you are iterating with i but sending products.id as argument... check that once again

Comment: Can I iterate with both?

Comment: please attach your models too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing this:

```
<td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{% url 'receipt' products.id %}">View</a></td>
```

However, `products.id` is empty or does not exist, so this is maybe what you want:

```
<td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{% url 'receipt' i.id %}">View</a></td>
```

**UPDATE**

The new error occurs because you are trying to iterate a single object. So, remove `{% for i in products %}` and `{% endfor %}`.

I also recommend to change the name of `products` since it is confusing and likely caused the error.

Comment: That fixed some of it. But now I'm receiving "'materialForm' object is not iterable". I made the products function to get specific Id's from each row. I have three objects in the database and I hope to link a page given their specific object information using their IDs.

Comment: @NickRizzolo, I just updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting  [ But now I'm receiving "'materialForm' object is not iterable". ] because **in the receipts.html , You are iterating the contents inside the products queryset with i but then inside the loop you are again using the the products queryset's name directly instead of using the created  iterator i...**

---

do the changes mentioned in the inventory.html and receipt.html and try again ..,

inventory.html code

```
                {% for i in items %}
                
            
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{i.Name_of_the_Material_per_specification}}</td>
                        <td>{{i.Site_Material_Code }}</td>
                        #change the next line to
                        <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{% url 'receipt' products.id %}">View</a></td>

                        #this
                        <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{% url 'receipt' i.id %}">View</a></td>
                        
                        
                    </tr>
                    
                
                {% endfor %}
```

RECIEPT.HTML

```
<div class="col-md">
        <div class="card card-body">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {% for i in products %}
                    #change the next line to
                    <p>Name: {{products.Name_of_the_Material_per_specification}}</p>
                    #this
                    <p>Name: {{i.Name_of_the_Material_per_specification}}</p>
                    
                    {% endfor %}
    
        </div>
    </div>
```

URLS.PY

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from inventory import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('main', views.inventory, name='inventory'),
    path('receipt/<str:pk>/', views.products, name="receipt")
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse

from django.template import loader
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from .models import *
from .forms import *



# Create your views here.
def inventory(request):
    items = materialForm.objects.all()
  
    return render(request, 'website/inventory.html', {'items': items})

def products(request, pk):
    products = materialForm.objects.get(id=pk)
    context = {'products':products }

    return render(request, 'website/receipt.html', context )
```